# Minecraft HashMap Floats Problems

Tags: java, hashmap, numbers, addition

I don't know why this is happenning, please somebody help.

```
if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("maisponto")){

        if(pontos.get(player.getName()) == null){

            pontos.put(player.getName(), 0f);
            player.sendMessage("Adicionado");

        }

        if(pontos.get(player.getName()) != null){
        Float ponto = pontos.get(player.getName());

        ponto += 1f;
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "Pontos: " + ChatColor.GREEN + ponto);
        }


    }
```

The problem is that the value is always 1 and its not going like 1, 2, 3...

The Hashmap is a String and a Float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually store the value back to the HashMap. After incrementing it by one, add this line:

```
pontos.put(player.getName(), ponto);
```

As a side note, if you're just storing integers, why are you using `Float`? Just use `Integer` instead and you'll be just fine. Plus, it makes it more clear what the value is for.